# Does breadcrumbs and url inconsistency affect SEO?

Tags: seo, url, wordpress, breadcrumbs

If a website has inconsistency between **URL structure** and **Breadcrumbs structure** is it good, neutral or bad for SEO?

For example on Yoast site "Wordpress Plugins" page `https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/`:

- Parent page according to URL is `https://yoast.com/wordpress/`
- Parent page according to Breadcrumb is `https://yoast.com/software/`

[image]

And same effect **but even more inconsistency** on the deeper level page `https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/`

[image]

The mentioned site belongs to a company that is considered the guru of SEO. This makes me think that inconsistency somehow could give better SEO results? Or at least not negatively affect SEO.

So, is it justifiable from SEO point of view to have inconsistent URL and Breadcrumb structure? It it reasonable? Or does it not affect SEO negatively?

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question! Cheers!!

Comment: Sorry but this is considered off-topic because its not about a site within your control. Reviews on Products, Software, Resources and 3rd party websites are considered off-topic as well. Please visit our help centre to avoid further disappointment.

Comment: @SimonHayter Clearly, this question is on the fence depending upon how you read it. I read it a an SEO question using Yoast as an example of where the interest comes from. For me, it was interesting from that perspective. You are right to put this on hold for the reason you cited. Cheers!!

Comment: Edited the question to be less about 3rd party website. The point of course is not to review a site not under my control. My intent is to ask a SEO question. And I used the site as illustration. Hopefully this will work?